# How to get product Custom Attribute Multiselect Value in order admin magento

Tags: admin, attributes, product-attribute

How to get product  Custom Attribute Multiselect Value in order admin magento

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

After this line

```
echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name');
```

I added My Custom product attribute Value

```
$_item->getPackaging();//this is multi select value
```

I am getting here option value like "2245" But i need label like "Bulk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setData('packaging', $_item->getPackaging()); 
$optionLabel = $product->getAttributeText('packaging');
```